# Protractor cucumber passing value from one step to Another step

Tags: protractor

What is the best way to share data between steps. Is there any best practices like scenario context or something of that sort in protrator?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global variables in your step defeinitions, or create a file and then in another step read it forom there.
I do not know that there is a way to pass it in feature file, not for the protractor, but selenium as well.
If you need more datils, please ask in comments.